# What is the quota limit of Google Analytics 4 Bigquery link

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I activated google analytics 4 bigquery linking, and it works correctly. I wonder what is the limitation of this link. Api metrics shows that link using api methods below.

```
google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.GetJob
google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.GetQueryResults
google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob
google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableDataService.List
```

But I can't found the exact match API name on bigquery documents.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert?hl=ja

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit for how many hits you can export from the free version of GA4 to BigQuery is 1M hits per day.

> Standard properties have a daily BigQuery Export limit of 1 million events. If your property consistently exceeds the export limit, the daily BigQuery export will be paused and previous days’ exports will not be reprocessed.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

If you go above that, Google will stop your pipeline.

There are only two solutions to overcome this that I know of.

1. Upgrade to GA360
2. Use [Parallel Tracking](https://reflectivedata.com/services/google-analytics-parallel-tracking/)

[Another relevant article](https://reflectivedata.com/how-to-avoid-google-analytics-4-ga4-bigquery-export-quota-limit-of-1-million-hits/) that describes avoiding the limits in GA4.

Comment: I reffered the document,
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Once you set up the link from GA360 to BigQuery, as far as I know, there is no limit to this link. According to the document, usually GA sends data 3 times a day to BigQuery. You will see partitioned table for GA data in BigQuery for each day. (This link is only available in Analytics 360, which is not free.)

For more information, refer to the official documents. [support.google.com/analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en#step2.1)

Also, limits and quotas for BigQuery.
[cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas)

About API names you listed appear here.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs

Comment: Thank you.
The document you told me is about Universal Analytics? I found the link for next gen GA4 export at the top of the page. I kind understand the Universal Analytics + 360 + Bigquery Export and GA4 Bigquery link is same or similar thing.
And both have the limit for cloud project and bigquery storage quota. is my understanding correct?

GA4 Big Query Export
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en&ref_topic=9359001

Comment: @Satoshi Watanabe  So your question is not the quota or limit on the link(between GA and BigQuery) but you want to know about limit and quota on BigQuery in general? Yes. There are limits and quotas on cloud resources like BigQuery specified by Google Cloud.

Comment: I didn't understand what technology GA"4" and BigQuery link has. GA4 link released three months ago.
And Yes, I want to know the precise limit of BigQuery API name of GetJob, GetQueryResults, InsertJob, TableDataService.List.

Comment: @SatoshiWatanabe  Quotas and limits of BigQuery is the link you posted. As for the API names, refer to this. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know audit meta formats. Metanames differ slightly from API method name. Each metanames probably mean the methods of jobs.get, jobs.getQueryResults, jobs.insert, tabledata.list. now I think I can reffer the quota documents. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SatoshiWatanabe  I'm glad to help. :)

Comment: In case you still need to collect >1M events per day, I would recommend checking out Parallel Tracking for GA4. https://reflectivedata.com/how-to-avoid-google-analytics-4-ga4-bigquery-export-quota-limit-of-1-million-hits/